# Create schema on mongoose whether to use 'new' keyword or not?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I understand what is the **use of `Schema` and `model` in mongoose**, however **when defining/creating a new `Schema`** there are **2 ways of doing it** (that I found of), and I'm confused by it,

**1st** way (**without `new` - no instance created**):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dbName');

// No 'new' keyword
var mySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    parameter1 : String,
    parameter2 : String
});

var modelName = mongoose.model('collectionName', mySchema);
```

and **2nd** way of doing it (**with `new` - an instance created**):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/dbName');

// There is 'new' keyword
var mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    parameter1 : String,
    parameter2 : String
});

var modelName = mongoose.model('collectionName', mySchema);
```

What's the differences between the two? when to use one or the other?

Answer (score 2):

Both way are fine, but according to code standard and mongoose library, we use 2nd way. It's follow extending & Implementation feature like OOP.

Schema & Model we use in nodejs for validation & restrict unwanted object & fields inserting into mongo collection.

Thats the reason for uses.